# Lebesgue measure of simplex (support of Dirichlet distribution)

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions, lebesgue-measure, simplex

I want to calculate the Lebesgue measure of standard $K-1$ simplex: $\{(x_1,...,x_K)~|~\sum_{i=1}^{K} x_i = 1 \mbox{ and } x_i \ge 0 \mbox{ for all } i \in [1,K]\}$ on $\mathbb{R}^K$. I think the measure is $0$ because the simplex is of dimension $K-1$.

However, the support of [Dirichlet distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_distribution#Support) is such simplex and Dirichlet distribution has a probability density function with respect to Lebesgue measure on the Euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^K$.

So I am very confused. How Dirichlet distribution could be absolute continuous w.r.t. Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}^K$? How to calculate the volume of simplex by Lebesgue integration?

Answer (score 3):

I found the answer by reading [this section in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_distribution#Random_number_generation). In fact, the Dirichlet measure is not absolutely continuous w.r.t. the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}^K$ but the one on on $\mathbb{R}^{K-1}$. The last variable $x_K$ is a bound variable, so the distribution is only w.r.t. $(x_1,...,x_{K-1})$.

I modified the Wikipedia page to remove this error.

Comment: I see. I find the density function on the Wikipedia page confusing then; it's denoted by $f(x_1, ...x_K; \alpha_1,...,\alpha_K)$, implying it's a function whose inputs are in $\mathbb{R}^K$, but we can't really integrate it w.r.t. the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}^{K-1}$...